# Dynamic Key Value pair storage class with interface in C# and ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, interface, azure-keyvault

Let's say I want to have an interface and class to store key value pairs from external provider (e.g. Azure KeyVault).

I have this interface:

```
namespace SampleNamespace.Interfaces 
{
    public interface IKeyVault 
    {
        string string1 { get; }
        string string2 { get; }
        string string3 { get; }
        //... more member variables
        string stringN { get; }

        //initialize the class with the values from the keyvault
        public Task<bool> Initialize();
    }
}
```

And then I have this implementation of the interface:

```
namespace SampleNamespace.Classes 
{
    public class AzureKeyVault : IKeyVault 
    {
        string string1 { get; private set; }
        string string2 { get; private set; }
        string string3 { get; private set; }
        ...
        string stringN { get; private set; }

        public async Task<bool> Initialize() 
        {
            if (AzureKeyVaultProvider.InitializeClient("somekey")) 
            {
                string1 = await AzureKeyVaultProvider.GetSecret("string1");
                //...more fetches
                stringN = await AzureKeyVaultProvider.GetSecret("stringN");

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can imagine these fetches take some time (for 6 values something like 4 seconds). Not every service that uses and initializes the class needs every value. Also some other values might be added to the future to the remote vault (whatever might that be, thus the interface). How can I make the variables dynamic and each initializer of the class to fetch and initialize only the ones it needs?

I tried making many initializers based on the calling service but that makes the usage of interface counterintuitive. Also I do not want to implement a getter function that asynchronously fetches each value. I want to initialize the required ones in one place in my code.

Comment: I think you can use the Lazy class and initialize it only when you need it,

here you can find an example : https://github.com/alirezanet/Husky.Net/blob/master/src/Husky/Services/Git.cs

here I need asynchronous operation that's why I have separate methods, but synchronously you can use your properties instead

Comment: You seem to imply that you know the keys that will be required a priori. If that's the case, Create sub-classes of AzureKeyVault that expose only the keys that are required. That way, you are not doing unnecessary work for each sub-class. Bonus, if there are any keys that are required by all sub-classes, they can be fetched in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is more of a comment than an answer, but as the current owner of the Key Vault SDK for .NET I can tell you that, by design, you cannot get multiple secret values in a single call. Listing and getting secrets are distinct operations that require separate permissions i.e., `secret/list` and `secret/get`.

If you know that at some point you will need multiple values, we actually recommend you store them that way. This is actually pretty common. You could serialize your class to JSON, and store and retrieve it as a JSON blob e.g.:

```cs
SecretClient client = new SecretClient(vaultUri, credential);
KeyVaultSecret secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);

Secrets secrets = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(secret.Value, SecretsGenerationContext.Default.Secrets)
    ?? throw new Exception("Corrupted secret");
Console.WriteLine($"Secret1: {secrets.Secret1}");
Console.WriteLine($"Secret2: {secrets.Secret2}");

class Secrets
{
    public string? Secret1 { get; set; }
    public string? Secret2 { get; set; }
}

[JsonSerializable(typeof(Secrets))]
[JsonSourceGenerationOptions(PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true, WriteIndented = true)]
partial class SecretsGenerationContext : JsonSerializerContext {};
```

It will be much faster this way as opposed to retrieving each individually. If you're using legacy access policies, you can't set permissions on individual secrets anyway. Even though this should be possible with RBAC, you may find it easier to manage separate applications with separate Key Vault, which may also help reduce cost even though Key Vault is already pretty inexpensive.